# Eliminar multiples objetos con casilla de verificación en una tabla

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist, checkbox, thymeleaf

soy nuevo en spring y estoy intentando eliminar las filas seleccionadas por medio de un checkbox, esta es mi tabla .html

```
<table class="table" id="tableActions">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Remove</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Debt Age Rule</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Reminder</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Frequency</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Reorder</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr th:each="configCampaign:${listConfigCampaigns}">
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox">
                                        </td>
                                        <td th:text="${configCampaign.debtagerule}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${configCampaign.remindebttype}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="'Every '+${configCampaign.every} + ' ' + ${configCampaign.unit}"></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Esta tabla me muestra datos de un arrayList en memoria, nada con base datos, necesito eliminar esos objetos seleccionados del array. De momento mi controlador lo tengo asi

```
@GetMapping("/deleteConfigureCampaign")
public String deleteConfig(@ModelAttribute ConfigCampaign configCampaign, Model model) {
    listConfigCampaigns.remove(configCampaign);
    return "redirect:/configureCampaign";
}
```

Asi se veria mi lista en el navegador y su boton para eliminar las filas seleccionadas del arraylist
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es mi clase modelo (ConfigCampaign) con la cual trabajo el arrayList

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int configid;
private String debtagerule;
private String remindebttype;
private int every;
private String unit;
private boolean selected;
//getters and setters
```

Gracias, espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Como envías la data del cliente al servidor?.

Comment: Para que funcione el `remove` de tus listas, tu objeto tiene que haber implementado el `equals` y el objeto `ConfigCompain`. Comparte más de tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrías probar de esta manera , encerrando las fila dentro de un form para  hacer un submit de los checkbox seleccionados

```
 <form name="unNombre" th:action="@{/deleteConfigureCampaign}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr th:each="configCampaign:${listConfigCampaigns}">

                                    <td th:text="${configCampaign.debtagerule}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${configCampaign.remindebttype}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="'Every '+${configCampaign.every} + ' ' + ${configCampaign.unit}"></td>
//En el th:value va lamanera que tengas de obtener el configid
                                    <td><input type="checkbox"
                            name="lista" id="listaElim" th:value="${ConfigCampaign.configid}"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

tu controlador ahora lo cambiarías por @PostMapping pasandole por parametros la lista de los checkbox como una lista de String

```
@PostMapping("/deleteConfigureCampaign")
public String deleteConfig(@RequestParam List<String> lista) 
//Recorres la lista de id
for (String stg : lista) {
//Pasas los datos de String a int que es el tipo de dato de tu configid
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(stg);
        //Aquí llamas a tu método eliminar con parametro id

}
return "redirect:/configureCampaign";
```

luego en el botón de eliminar todos los seleccionados lo configuras para que haga el submit del formulario en el evento onclick y listo tendría que eliminar todos los seleccionados .......saludos